# (Cantonese) How to say there are always two sides to a story?

Tags: cantonese, hong-kong

I'm talking to a friend about something, and she's only presenting one side. So I want to ask about the other side and say, "there are always two sides to every story." What's the best way to say this in Cantonese?

兩全
兩頭蛇

Those don't seem right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 另有內情 `ling6 jau5 noi6 cing4` fits the bill.

Answer (score 3):

> 凡事都有兩面。
>   There are always two sides to every story.

凡 = every
事 = issue (story)
都 = always
有 = has
兩 = two
面 = sides

Answer (score 2):

I think 凡事都有两面性 is okay. 凡事=任何事=everything. 任何事物都应该从正反两面考虑。有其利，必有其弊。

Answer (score 2):

Not a Cantonese word per se, but you can use the good old `兼听则明`, which means "Listening to both sides of a story makes Jack a bright boy."

A complete form would be `兼听则明, 偏信则暗`. The latter part means "Believing only one side of a story makes Jack a dumb git."